# 2 decimal places in web grid for mvc - need total value to display value with 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

2 decimal places in web grid for mvc - need total value to display value with 2 decimal places

```
@grid.GetHtml(

            tableStyle: "table",
            fillEmptyRows: true,
            headerStyle: "header",
            footerStyle: "grid-footer",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: new[]
            {
                grid.Column(columnName: "SelfBillInvoiceNumber", header: "Invoice Number"), //the model fields to display

                grid.Column(columnName: "SelfBillItemTotalvalue", header: "Total Value")
            })
```

Comment: here x and y are the values in the entity which comes from the model

Comment: The changes you've made go largely against the spirit of Stack Overflow. As it stands, edit logs are completely open to everyone to see, so the original text is already publicly visible. Editing it only increases the difficulty of maintaining the associated answers and provides no additional benefit to the site's users.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the type of your `SelfBillItemTotalvalue` property, I can only recommend this:

```
grid.Column(
      columnName: "SelfBillItemTotalvalue", 
      header: "Total Value",
      format: item => item.ToString("#.##")
)
```

Comment: here x and y are the values in the entity which comes from the model

Comment: I get the following error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments'

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can add column like this also

```
columns: grid.Columns(                        
     grid.Column(header: "SelfBillItemTotalvalue", format: @<text>String.Format("{0:0.##}", @item.SelfBillItemTotalvalue) </text>, style: "remo")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
grid.Column(columnName: "SelfBillItemTotalvalue", header: "Total Value")
```

in this one:

```
grid.Column(header: "Total Value", format: item => String.Format("{0:0.00}", item.SelfBillItemTotalvalue))
```